# How can I use a release mode DLL in a debug mode program without encountering breakpoint errors?

Tags: c, debugging, ssl, dll

I want to use `libssl.dll` which is built in release mode in my program when my C program was built in release mode or debug mode. But I get a break in the `ntdll.dll` when my debug-mode program calls `X509_free()` from release-mode `libssl.dll` and here is the stack:

[image]

And it is in a `free()` function in SSSL source code.
by the way, I am using Run-time dynamic linking to use the functions from `libssl.dll` when the matter occurs and when I use Load-time dynamic linking to use the functions from `libssl.dll`, everything is fine.
I have try to change the order of calling `SSL_free()` and `X509_free()` and it works but I don't know why:

```
// This order works but I don't know why.
if (port->peer)
{
    X509_free(port->peer);
    port->peer = NULL;
}

if (port->ssl)
{
    SSL_shutdown(port->ssl);
    SSL_free(port->ssl);
    port->ssl = NULL;
}
```

What might be the cause of this matter?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: Mixing release- and debug-mode libraries on Windows?  I've yet to find a way that's successful, and the problems usually manifest in memory corruption errors, likely because Window's debug and release runtimes literally use different allocators.  The debug one will fill memory with debug patterns, the release one won't, for example.

Comment: What is your way to manage this matter? I really want to know and I appreciate it if you can share with me:) @Andrew Henle